# How do I get mdfind to look in /opt?

Tags: command-line, spotlight

`mdfind` does not seem to find files in `/opt`.

e.g.

```
$ mdfind -onlyin /opt -name Dockerfile
$
```

`find` produces the expected result

```
$ find /opt -name Dockerfile
/opt/homebrew/Dockerfile
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.17.5/libexec/src/crypto/elliptic/internal/fiat/Dockerfile
$
```

Why might `/opt` be invisible to `mdfind`?  Is there some system setting that will get `mdfind` to work?

EDIT:

On my system, `/opt` is just a regular directory.  It is not a mount point or a symlink or anything special.

```
$ ls -ld /opt
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 Jan  3  2022 /opt

$ df -kh /opt
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk3s5  460Gi  359Gi   75Gi    83% 3302051 4824674469    0%   /System/Volumes/Data

$ mdls /opt
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate = 2022-01-03 20:30:37 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate      = 2021-01-25 11:56:41 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode       = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags       = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon     = 0
kMDItemFSInvisible         = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery      = 0
kMDItemFSLabel             = 0
kMDItemFSName              = "opt"
kMDItemFSNodeCount         = 2
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID      = 0
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID       = 0
kMDItemFSSize              = 2
kMDItemFSTypeCode          = ""
```

Comment: `find` is a real-time search of the filesystem.  `mdfind` uses the Spotlight database.  Spotlight does not index every directory.

Comment: @MarcWilson How does Spotlight decide what directories to index?   If possible, I'd very much like to get /opt into the Spotlight database.

Comment: Just to confirm. mdfind fails to return any items with either search by name or search by content.  But Finder search does return items for search by name (not by content) - that seems odd to me.

Comment: `mdfind` works for me in `/opt`. Is your `opt` just a directory, or does it point to a mount somewhere else?

Comment: @SpinUp `/opt` is just a regular directory on my system.  I have added details to my original question.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the test/debugging version of mdimport (in the comments below)? When I run that, I get:
`Imported '/opt' of type 'public.folder' with no plugIn.`
`25 attributes returned` `{ ...`

Answer (score 1):

`mdimport /opt`

will perform a one-time import. I believe that you will have to periodically re-run this command to keep the index updated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I tried `mdimport /opt` and tried my original mdfind command, but got no output.

Comment: @sigjuice Doesn't work for me either. Confirmed further by the output of `mdls /opt/<file>` which return minimal metadata.  Duplicate one of the files to /usr and there is expected metadata and mdfind works as expected with results for both search by name and search by content.

Comment: Could it be a permissions problem? Try the `mdimport` command with sudo? Or turn on debugging output like `mdimport -t -d2 /opt`?

Comment: Another idea: the GUI version of this is to exclude the directory in spotlight's system preference pane, then remove it from the exclusion list. That should trigger a re-index.